# How to set two values for same definition in enum, C#

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

I am trying to compare values that I am getting from web service, but sometimes I get int value, sometimes i get string. So it would be great that i could only check for Type.value1.

for example:

```
enum Type { value1 = 1 , value1="one"}
```

and like that for more value2, etc...
But of course, I cannot do this because it I cannot add two definitons for value1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve, there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes a type that behaves mostly like an enum but has some richer behaviour can be very useful:

```
public sealed class MyFakeEnum {

  private MyFakeEnum(int value, string description) {
    Value = value;
    Description = description;
  }

  public int Value { get; private set; }

  public string Description { get; private set; }

  // Probably add equality and GetHashCode implementations too.

  public readonly static MyFakeEnum Value1 = new MyFakeEnum(1, "value1");
  public readonly static MyFakeEnum Value2 = new MyFakeEnum(2, "value2");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can consider adding attributes to the enums and use reflection.

```
enum Type 
{ 
    [Description("One")]
    value1 = 1 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also make use of using decorating the enum with a description attribute as described by BSoD_ZA. But I would suggest that you then implement an extension method for the enumeration to obtain the string description for example:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{

  public static string ToDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum enumValue) where TEnum : struct
  {
    return ReflectionService.GetClassAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>(enumValue);
  }
}

enum Type 
{ 
  [Description("One")]
  value1 = 1 
}

var value = Type.Value1;
Console.Writeline(value.ToDescription());
```